# How do I expand the blue highlighted text in UIWebView?

Tags: ios, uiwebview

After tap and hold and release, text is highlighted in UIWebView.  The user can expand the text by dragging the dots, but is there a way I can automatically do it in code?  For example, the user selects "Abraham" and I expand it to be "Abraham Lincoln".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. That feature of the UIWebView cannot be modified using Apple-approved public APIs. This also applies to the magnifying glass.